# Marshal.SizeOf structure returns excessive number

Tags: c#, struct, sizeof

I have the following structure

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SFHeader
{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string FileName;

    public int Offset;

    public short Size;

    public byte Flags;

    public byte Source;


    public long LastWriteTime;


    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        var buffer = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, buffer, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return buffer;
    }


    public static SFHeader FromBytes(byte[] buffer)
    {
        var str = new SFHeader();
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, ptr, size);
        str = (SFHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return str;
    }

}
```

I need to convert my structure to an array of byte (to send as packet with socket), so I use the `GetBytes` method, but it returns an array of `24` bytes instead of an array of `21` bytes:

- Filename (string): 5 bytes
- Offset (int): 4 bytes
- Size (short): 2 bytes
- Flags (byte): 1 byte
- Source (byte): 1 byte
- LastWriteTime (long): 8 bytes

So: 5+4+2+1+1+8 = 21 bytes.
This happens because `Marshal.SizeOf` returns 24, why?
And it seems that the the bytes in excess are placed after the bytes of the string, in fact for example the following structure:

```
var header = new SFHeader()
{
   FileName = "aaaa",
   Offset = 1,
   Size = 1
};
```

is converted to the following buffer:

```
[0] = 97
[1] = 97
[2] = 97
[3] = 97
[4] = 0
[5] = 0
[6] = 0
[7] = 0
[8] = 1
[9] = 0
[10] = 0
[11] = 0
[12] = 1
[13] = 0
... The following are all zero (0)
```

The fifth, sixth and seventh are the bytes in excess.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The string has a weird length, so the other fields got realigned. Using Explicit Layout may fix that. "Sequential" does not mean "contiguous".

Comment: Does the string always has the same length?

Comment: @SynerCoder yes, a maximum of 5 bytes.

Comment: Then instead of a string might I suggest char[5]

Comment: @harold If i try I get a System.TypeLoadException.

Comment: MarshalAsAttribute.SizeConst Field : Indicates the number of elements in the fixed-length array or the number of characters (not bytes) in a string to import. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeconst(v=vs.110).aspx 
It's clearly stated "number of characters (not bytes)" so it might be related to encoding.

Comment: @Paciv you might be right, how can I tell to the compiler that it is the number of bytes, and not the number of characters?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx at ByValTStr element, then follow the link to the CharSet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're running into a byte-alignment issue.  In an attempt to keep fields on word boundaries for speed of access, the compiler is padding your `string` with 3 extra bytes.  To fix this, use the `Pack` field of the `StructLayoutAttribute`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]  // notice the packing here
public struct SFHeader
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string FileName;

    public int Offset;

    public short Size;

    public byte Flags;

    public byte Source;

    public long LastWriteTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [fixed size buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a string.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct SFHeader
{
    public fixed char FileName[5];
    public int Offset;
    public short Size;
    public byte Flags;
    public byte Source;
    public long LastWriteTime;

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        //omitted
    }

    public static SFHeader FromBytes(byte[] buffer)
    {
        //omitted
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives a size of 32, not 21.  Even if you replace `char` with `byte`, you still get 24 from the `Marshal.SizeOf()` call.