# Different bool size

Tags: c#, boolean, marshalling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Marshal.SizeOf structure returns excessive number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233812/marshal-sizeof-structure-returns-excessive-number)

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) states that `sizeof(bool)` is **1** byte. But when I put bool in struct , sizeof struct become **4** byte. Can someone explain this behavior?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Sample1
{
    public bool a1;
}

int size1 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Sample1));  // 4
int size2 = sizeof (bool);                     // 1
```

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf` is measuring a **very different** thing to `sizeof`...

Comment: It might have something to do with alignment. Did you try adding Pack=1 to the StructLayout attribute's constructor?

Comment: @Botz3000,edze,Rawling - tried with Pack=1,result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly compare `sizeof` and `Marshal.SizeOf`. For example, if we measure it the same way, we get the same result:

```
static unsafe void Main() { // unsafe is needed to use sizeof here
    int size1 = sizeof(Sample1); // 1
}
```

*Presumably*, `Marshal` is assuming per-field alignment of 4 bytes.

Comment: So it means that I cant use bool fields in C# struct when marshaling c++ struct with bool field? What type should I use then? byte?

Comment: @Stecya I would expect byte to align the same; however, different approaches are used in different contexts. It could already *just work*

Comment: When there bool field marshal doesn't convert struct properly,changed it to byte and got right result. Just curious why it behaves that way

Answer (score 1):

when using structs/class there size is always aligned to a specific size ,on each architecture it can be different, but it's usually 4 so if you have int after the bool it we start at a multiplication of 4, cause processors reads in 4 bytes chunks.
This is something worth thinking about when setting the order of members in classes (or structures)

exmaples:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Sample1
{
    public bool a1;//take 1 byte but align to 4
}
public struct Sample2
{
    public bool a1;//take 1 byte but align to 4
    public int  a2;//take 4 bytes (32bit machine) start at a multiplication of 4
    public bool a3;//take 1 byte but align to 4
}
public struct Sample3
{
    //here the compiler (with the right optimizations) can put all the bools one after the other without breaking the alignment
    public bool a1;
    public bool a2;
    public bool a3;
    public bool a4;
    public int  a5;
}
int size1 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Sample1));  // 4
int size1 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Sample2));  // 12
int size1 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Sample3));  // 8
int size2 = sizeof (bool);                     // 1
```

Comment: I Actually get different result for Sample3 in your code snippet, it is **20**

Comment: @Stecya - when I say "The compiler knows", it's actually depends on the optimization settings you define for the compilation. I put the numbers using my definitions (: . I've fixed the answer to be more explanatory.

Comment: Ok,I change bool to byte in Sample1 and got 1 byte as result,so it clearly not align issue